# Query results based on the current date

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to figure out how to select results based on the current date. The script will be ran daily but I am unsure of how to do it automatically.

```
SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE OrderDate='2008-11-11'
```

What I am trying now

```
SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE OrderDate=NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Comment: which database is this?

Comment: Sorry, i added it to the post. MySQL

Comment: No don't do that.  Add a tag instead.

Comment: Also, can you show some research effort?  What have you found on the topic, and how is it not working for you or what do you need clarified?

Comment: NOW() includes the time use CURDATE()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM Orders 
WHERE OrderDate >= DATE(NOW())
AND OrderDate < DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

**EDIT**

I always tend to write the above style of query when I expect the column that I am checking against to have a time component as well.

If your `OrderDate` column does not have a time component, then as `Lennart` pointed out, you can simply do:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Orders 
WHERE OrderDate = DATE(NOW())
```

**EDIT 2**: Mihai's comment on your question is also relevant.  You can simply use `CURDATE()` instead of `DATE(NOW())`.

Comment: Why not `OrderDate = DATE(NOW())`?

Comment: DATE(NOW()) does the trick, as well as sstan's. I was missing the extra parentheses

Comment: @Lennart: Well, I don't know for a fact that `OrderDate` doesn't have a time portion.  So I went safe in case it did.

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE (OrderDate  > DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 DAY))
```